# Restoring deleted questions and answers here on Superuser…

Tags: discussion, delete

I don't know how I did but it appears I have deleted all of my questions and answers here on Superuser. How do I restore them? I want to restore them and then go through them so I can "mark" the right answer. Never did that and I want to.

Comment: You may well have been on [meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/) rather than [SU]. For questions related to the site itself, for example this one, you should be asking on meta. Meta is where you ask *about* questions, answers and the site in general, the main site is where you ask about computer problems.

Comment: There are 39 questions and 8 answers showing on your SU profile so if you deleted them all, you didn't do a good job of it.  :-)  Mokubai may be on to something.  For example, if you were on Meta and checked your profile, you will see only your Meta posts.

Comment: Thank you and I will try to delete better next time. :-)

Comment: (Seriously, GUI designers take note: this interface is quite confusing. As for me traveling: I'm handicapped and stuck in the same nursing home for the last five years)